# How to automate Crystal Report exports?

Tags: perl, crystal-reports, automation, activex

I don't know the exact terminology but I'm trying to download a file from a website which, i guess, runs ActiveX Crystal Viewer. I want to be able to hit the extract button and save it as a specific file format. Is that possible with Perl?

I don't know if this will help, but it is the object in the webpage:

`OBJECT id=CRViewer codeBase="/rePortal_CrystalReportViewers10/ActiveXControls/activexviewer.cab#Version=10,0,0,280" classid=CLSID:A1B8A30B-8AAA-4a3e-8869-1DA509E8A011 width="100%" height="100%" VIEWASTEXT

PARAM NAME="EnablePopupMenu" VALUE="-1"

PARAM NAME="EnableExportButton" VALUE="-1"

PARAM NAME="EnableSearchExpertButton" VALUE="0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Win32::OLE::CrystalRuntime::Application](http://search.cpan.org/~mrdvt/Win32-OLE-CrystalRuntime-Application-0.12/lib/Win32/OLE/CrystalRuntime/Application.pm) Module that you should look at. It allows you to control Crystal Reports

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Crystal exports with a number of tools on the market.

I recommend Report Runner @ http://www.reportrunner.com.